# Visual Studio Code only debugs on Windows, Chrome and Edge, but fatal error on an emulator or a physical android device. How can I solve this?

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, gradle, android-emulator, adb

I installed visual studio code, visual studio 2022 with windows C++, Android Studio, Powershell 7, running on Windows 11 version 22H2. In Visual Studio Code I began by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P then clicked on "Flutter: New Project", then selected "Application" and started with the default Flutter demo app. This debugs on Windows, Chrome and Edge without any problems. However, every time I try to run the debug on an emulator or a physical device I get a fatal error.

## Below is what I have installed:

```
C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\AppProjects\debug_my_app\debug_my_app>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1928], locale
    en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.10.5 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository h t t p s : // github. com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (4 weeks ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.4)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.6.33815.320
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https : // plugins. jetbrains. com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https : // plugins. jetbrains. com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] VS Code (version 1.80.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.68.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM G975F (mobile) • R58M50T2ZDR • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows     • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version
      10.0.22621.1928]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.199       
    • Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 114.0.1823.67       

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

## Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\AppProjects\debug_my_app\debug_my_app>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G975F in debug mode...
[Fatal Error] tink-1.3.0-rc2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
               > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
                     > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:9.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:9.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.1/asm-analysis-9.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
               > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
                     > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.1/asm-commons-9.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
               > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
                     > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:9.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:9.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.1/asm-util-9.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
               > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
                     > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0
      > Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/crypto/tink/tink/1.3.0-rc2/tink-1.3.0-rc2.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
               > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
                     > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:9.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:9.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.1/asm-util-9.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
               > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
                     > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.1/asm-commons-9.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
               > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
                     > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.1.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.1/asm-tree-9.1.pom
            > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
               > Could not resolve org.ow2:ow2:1.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
                     > Resetting to invalid mark

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             85.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

## Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
 name: debug_my_app
 description: A new Flutter project.
 publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

 version: 1.0.0+1

 environment:
   sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

 dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter


   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

 dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
     sdk: flutter

   flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

 flutter:

   uses-material-design: true
```

## here is the build.gradle file

```
 buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
     }

     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
     }
 }

 allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
     }
 }

 rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
 subprojects {
     project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
 }
 subprojects {
     project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
 }

 tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

## here is the gradle properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

These steps have been taken already:
Debugging is enabled on the physical android device
Preloaded two emulators
Cleared the Gradle cache
rebuilt the project to try again
Debugging from Android Studio as well as from Visual Studio Code
Run Flutter Doctor without errors
Run Flutter Clean
Run Flutter Pub Get
Run Dart Fix --apply
There is a stable internet connection
I use the free version of Proton VPN and tried with this activated and also with it deactivated.
I also use Avast free version anti virus, but without the VPN.
In Chrome I have VeePN but this is not activated, and the debug in Chrome works fine either way.
Invalidated caches and restarted android Studio
I have also updated my environment variables JAVA_HOME path to point to JDK-19.
I cannot tell if my ADB is installed correctly, though.

Comment: Please do not post error messages as image as it makes it difficult to read. Just copy and paste it as text into your question.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I have updated the write up and replaced the error image with text. I had to put spaces in the web link references to be able to submit the question, I hope that is ok.

Comment: Alls the texts you have posted contain defect links (with spaces in between). is this some sort of copy-paste problem or were the links really show this way `https : //repo. maven.apache.org`. The links that could not be donloaded are active and work without problems. Therefore it seems to be a network problem on your side.

Comment: I had to put spaces in the links because otherwise I could not submit the error ( I don't have enough points in stack overflow to paste more than 10 links). The original error did not contain the spaces.

Comment: That was because you used the wrong text format. Surround it by three backticks `\`\`\`` to format a section as code. Then links are not clickable and you should be able to post it even with low reputation.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed this now. The message is exactly as it appears in Visual Studio Code.